# Refresh Current Page after sweetalert Ok Popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sweetalert

I want to refresh current page after Sweet Alert

Below is the javascript code in my C# code
    enter code here

```
  url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please enter the correct data');window.location='" + url + "';", true);
```

Issue

```
 url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "swal('success','Please enter the correct data','success');window.location='" + url + "';", true);
```

Page is getting refresh but sweet alert is getting missed
Please suggest Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved on Ok button click 
Jquery was implemented at the client side

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".swal-button").click(function () {
            //location.reload(); 
            window.location = 'Profile.aspx';
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference between alert() and swal() which you seem to be missing:

```
function foo(){    
  alert("Hi");
  console.log("Hi");
}
```

When the alert pops up, unless you acknowledge the message, the next statement does not get executed.

```
function foo(){    
      swal("Hi");
      console.log("Hi");
    }
```

the log statement gets executed irrespective of the acknowledgement of the user.

So the appropriate snippet for you would be:

```
swal('success','Please enter the correct data','success').then((value) => {
  window.location=url
})
```

Though for some older versions you might have to do it this way

```
swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  icon: "success"
}, function(value){
    window.location=url;
});
```

You can find the documentation here at: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples

Comment: after adding this snippet into my scriptmanager alert is coming but disappering immediately  swal('success','Please enter the correct data','success').then((value) => {
  window.location=url
})

Comment: Can you please provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve?
The above snippet successfully redirects to the provided URL when the success button is clicked.

Comment: there is profile page where some information is manditory where i am updating data after the refresh due to which refresh is important for me please suggest some thing which would refresh as well as shows pop

Comment: So after refresh of the page, the pop up must still be present?

Comment: Ya that should be happen but it is getting disapper

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It may help you out.

```
 url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "swal('success','Please enter the correct data','success');window.location.href='" + url + "';", true);
```